# Strange behavior when scaling_factor parameter is set

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2.1 and now trying to understand how it works when `scaling_factor` paramerter is set to some value.

According to the documentation value of field is multiplied by `scaling_factor` and then stored as `long` at index time. When `scaling_factor` is 100 I expect that value 1.234 will be stored internally as 123 and after that can be found in index as 1.23. What I see now is value 1.234 does not lose its precision and I can get it from index in its original form: 1.234.

Is it a bug in this version of Elasticsearch? If not can someone explain what is happening under the hood?

**UPDATE**

@Val's answer clarified behavior of Elasticsearch but I'd like to understand why it is possible to find document by original raw value although index contains only scaled value. For example in case of the following mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "num": {
        "type": "scaled_float",
        "scaling_factor": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can index document

```
{
  "num": 1.234
}
```

and then find it with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "num": 1.234
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that query above would not find anything because index contains only rounded value 1.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `1.234` in the source document, it's normal, ES never modifies anything in the source document itself.

Given this mapping:

```
PUT scaling
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "num": {
        "type": "scaled_float",
        "scaling_factor": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you store this document

```
PUT scaling/_doc/1
{
  "num": "1.234"
}
```

Then retrieving the document, will yield the same data as you indexed:

```
GET scaling/_doc/1
=>
{
  "num": "1.234"
}
```

However, retrieving the doc value of the `num` field will yield what you expect:

```
GET scaling/doc/_search
{
  "docvalue_fields": ["num"],
  "script_fields": {
    "doc_value": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc.num.value"
      }
    },
    "raw_value": {
      "script": {
        "source": "params._source.num"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

=>

```
  {
    "_index" : "scaling",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "fields" : {
      "raw_value" : [
        "1.234"                  <--- raw value that was sent for indexing
      ],
      "doc_value" : [
        1.23                     <--- scaled doc value that was indexed
      ],
      "num" : [
        1.23                     <--- scaled doc value that was indexed
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for response! It became clearer for me, but I still don't understand why I'm able to find document by matching `num` field against value 1.23 as well as 1.234? I expected that second variant would fail because actually indexed value is 1.23.

Comment: Please update your question with the query you're sending

Comment: I updated my question with the example of simple query. Can you explain what's happening please?

Comment: A wild guess would be that ES applies the same scaling to the query value and only then the match is performed.

Comment: Reasonable but in this case I would be able to find my document by value "1.235" thanks to rounding. However it is not true.

Comment: 1.235 is rounded to 1.24, if you try with 1.233 and 1.232 you'll find it too

Comment: Oh, what a shame! :)  My own comment contained an answer to my question and I didn't see it. Thank you! I'm going to accept your answer.